# Qt Program has unexpectedly finished for no reason

Tags: c++, qt, crash

I am new to Qt and trying to make my first Qt application. I found that I am getting **"the program has unexpectedly finished"** error for no apparent reason to me. I commented out all the code and uncommented them line by line and it seems to be only certain lines of my code that are generating this error. I can't for the life of me understand why this would be happening.

I have a main window that works perfectly fine. All the layouts and connections work, etc. When I click a certain button, it opens a new window. This window also works perfectly fine. When a certain button is clicked, a third window is opened. This is where the issue lies. For no apparent reason, specific lines are generating problems. I have a vertical layout object and when I try to `addLayout(layout_horizontal)` I get the unexpected finish error. In the next line after that, I add a grid layout with no issues, and can add two buttons to the horizontal layout with no issues. Why would my `addLayout(layout_horizontal)` not work but `addLayout(layout_grid)` does?

I do a `button[i][j] = new QPushButton(this)` and this also generates the same error. It is not an issue with my pointers because the same code runs fine in my Xcode environment.

What baffles me the most is that my `this->size = size` line causes this unexpected finish error! I have a private int size declared in my header, and then have int size parameter in my constructor. Why would that assignment cause my program to unexpectedly finish? That seems to make no sense to me at all.

And even more than that, if I copy my entire `.h` and `.cpp` files and paste them into a different Qt project in a different folder, the code works perfectly fine. No unexpected finish. Nothing.

Could it be that my project is somehow corrupted? Or there is a bug in the Qt development environment that is causing this code to be compiled incorrectly and cause a runtime error?

I am so confused and frustrated because the my code should work but it doesn't.

I have attached the code below.

This code works fine

```cpp
GameWindow::GameWindow(int size, QWidget *previous) : QWidget() {

    this->previous = previous;

    int button_size = 0;

    switch (size) {

    case 10:
        button_size = 50;
        break;
    case 20:
        button_size = 35;
        break;
    case 30:
        button_size = 30;
        break;

    }

    //this->size = size; NOTICE THIS LINE IS COMMENTED
    map = new Button**[size];
    button_flag = new QPushButton(tr("&Flag"), this);
    button_quit = new QPushButton(tr("&Quit"), this);
    layout_grid = new QGridLayout;
    layout_vertical = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout_horizontal = new QHBoxLayout;

    //set up the layout
    this->setLayout(layout_vertical);
    //layout_vertical->addLayout(layout_horizontal);
    layout_vertical->addLayout(layout_grid);
    layout_horizontal->addWidget(button_flag);
    layout_horizontal->addWidget(button_quit);
    layout_grid->setSpacing(0);

    //set up buttons
    button_flag->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    button_quit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    button_flag->setFixedHeight(50);
    button_quit->setFixedHeight(50);
    connect(button_quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
    connect(button_flag, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        map[i] = new Button*[size];
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            //map[i][j] = new Button(this);
            //map[i][j]->setFixedSize(button_size, button_size);
            //layout_grid->addWidget(map[i][j], i, j);
            //connect(map[i][j], SIGNAL(clicked()), map[i][j], SLOT(button_clicked()));
        }
    }

    this->setFixedSize(this->minimumWidth(), this->minimumHeight());
    initialize_bombs();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            count_neighboring_bombs(i, j);
        }
    }

}
```

This code unexpectedly finishes

```cpp
GameWindow::GameWindow(int size, QWidget *previous) : QWidget() {

    this->previous = previous;

    int button_size = 0;

    switch (size) {

    case 10:
        button_size = 50;
        break;
    case 20:
        button_size = 35;
        break;
    case 30:
        button_size = 30;
        break;

    }

    this->size = size; //NOTICE THIS LINE IS NO LONGER COMMENTED
    map = new Button**[size];
    button_flag = new QPushButton(tr("&Flag"), this);
    button_quit = new QPushButton(tr("&Quit"), this);
    layout_grid = new QGridLayout;
    layout_vertical = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout_horizontal = new QHBoxLayout;

    //set up the layout
    this->setLayout(layout_vertical);
    //layout_vertical->addLayout(layout_horizontal);
    layout_vertical->addLayout(layout_grid);
    layout_horizontal->addWidget(button_flag);
    layout_horizontal->addWidget(button_quit);
    layout_grid->setSpacing(0);

    //set up buttons
    button_flag->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    button_quit->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    button_flag->setFixedHeight(50);
    button_quit->setFixedHeight(50);
    connect(button_quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
    connect(button_flag, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        map[i] = new Button*[size];
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            //map[i][j] = new Button(this);
            //map[i][j]->setFixedSize(button_size, button_size);
            //layout_grid->addWidget(map[i][j], i, j);
            //connect(map[i][j], SIGNAL(clicked()), map[i][j], SLOT(button_clicked()));
        }
    }

    this->setFixedSize(this->minimumWidth(), this->minimumHeight());
    initialize_bombs();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            count_neighboring_bombs(i, j);
        }
    }

}
```

I know that sometimes errors will arise but cleaning the project and running `qmake` before building again fixes it. Maybe the solution is some sort of trick like that. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. While I see that you've commented out parts of your code, we still need to see a [mre] (header file, main.cpp included). I'm guessing you're inheriting from QWidget; unless you have a `size` member, `this->size` `this->size` will refer to [`QWidget::size()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop) getter function, which can't be assigned with an int.

Comment: You need to run your application under a debugger.  That should (hopefully) give you some hints as to what's going wrong and why.

Comment: I do have my own size member. That line isn't the only one producing an error. Why does my add layout call product an error once but not the other times? Why does the code work when copied and pasted into another project? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have no (own) `size` member in the `GameWindow` class.

If so, then you are assigning an `int` to [QWidget's](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) size member, which is of type `QSize`. I would expect the compiler to complain, but I as I don't know how your header looks like it is difficult to tell.

If you have a `int size` member in `GameWindow` that may also be a cause, as `QWidget` has already have a member with that name...

Comment: Maybe he needs to do this: `this.resize(size, size);`

Comment: Note that `QWidget::size` isn't actually of type `QSize`.  Rather it's a non-static member function with return type `QSize` so its type is `QSize (QWidget::*)() const`.

Comment: I have my own size member as I explained in the question of type int. To reiterate, my code compiles fine, I just get a runtime error. I also copied and pasted the code into another project and it works fine with no runtime error. That is why I'm confused. If there is an error with my code, it should always be an error. But mine seems to only be wrong in the one project and not in any others.

Comment: @mlovick In that case I'd **strongly** reccommend that you edit your question to remove redundant code (i.e. the part where you essentially pasted the whole thing again, only with this->size = size commented out) and instead add the header of the class - i.e. as TrebledJ said: the code for a [minmal reproducibleexample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). People are trying to help you on a volunteer basis - try to make it easy for them to help you (e.g. by making making the code easy to read).